# Error when I use a relational callback in a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to have read-only access to model's attributes (:test) that is related to another model (:query) by a `has_many` association.

I can get the associated :test object to save when I create and associate a new :query, but I can't work with that associated :test's attributes in a `before_create' method.

From what I'm reading in the [API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) I should be able to use the association method (`@test = @query.test.whatever`) to use the "whatever" attribute, but I am getting the following error when I try to run that code: `private method 'test' called for nil:NilClass`.

:query is related to :test in a `belongs_to` relationship...

I've tried @test = @query.test.build to instantiate the test object in my method, but that does not work either.

Comment: can you post the code for the two models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply got a name collision. Every object in Ruby has its private method `test`.

Comment: I renamed the "test" model to "testcase" and I still get the same error. `private method 'testcase' called for nil:NilClass`. So annoying. I'm sure I'm just doing something stupid, but I can't figure it out...

Comment: Renaming the model isn't enough. You have to rename your association (`belongs_to :testcase`). Also there is a table called `tests` in your database. You have to fix this as well (the simplest way: write `set_table_name :testcases` inside your model).